# scheduledLocalNotifications showing wrong timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, uilocalnotification

i can get list of my `scheduledLocalNotifications` in my table view with this code perfectly ;

```
NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

but the only problem is , my local notifications are firing on correct time but showing  with wrong time zone on the list.

I'm also using `systemTimeZone` for scheduling my local notification like this ;

```
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

What is the correct way to get a list of `scheduledLocalNotifications` with the correct time zone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by *"showing with wrong time zone on the list"* ? How is that list created and displayed?

Comment: I've created table view and get scheduledLocalNotifications with this code ; NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem when after i had already scheduled a notification at 3:30 pm and it was correctly scheduled  when i NSLog it's fireDate it'll show up in a different time zone and that's how i fixed it.

```
[localNotification.fireDate descriptionWithLocale:NSGregorianCalendar]
```

this will return fire date with the Gregorian local (or you should use whatever local you have used when scheduling your local notification)